# Error when trying to self-update composer

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php, sudo

when I trying to self-update composer I get "Permission denied" error message, but when I try to do same command with "sudo" - I get error message "command not found". Please help me..

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terminal with sudo I type full path to composer.phar and it's work for me!

sudo /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

Comment: How do I make it so I can just use composer self-update without having to do that?

Comment: I agree. I've gone into my bash file (~/.bash_profile) or my ZSH file (~/.zshrc) and updated my path to have this!

Comment: @NicholasDecker Hey, it's been 4 years since you asked but this might still be helpful, the official docs say this: `If you like to install it only for your user and avoid requiring root permissions, you can use ~/.local/bin instead which is available by default on some Linux distributions.`

Answer (score -1):

For me this worked:

```
sudo -H composer self-update
```