# composer self-update error rename

Tags: terminal, composer-php, sudo

when I try to self-update composer I get "Permission denied" error message, but when I try to do the same command with "sudo" - I get error message "command not found".

Same problem as here:
[link to the similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679994/error-when-trying-to-self-update-composer)

But the solutions to type into the terminal:

sudo /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

or

sudo -H composer self-update

won't work for me. I just get command not found messages:
sudo: /usr/bin/composer.phar: command not found

I work on a Mac and some months ago I remember that it worked.

Comment: Check your file permissions. I assume it's a developer box, so give this a try `chmod 777 /usr/bin/composer.phar`.

Comment: thanks for your idea! my composer.phar is in the bash directory. From there I fire chmod 777 composer.phar, but I get "there is no such file or directory". The same if I just type chmod 777 /usr/bin/composer.phar

Comment: Hmm, what about trying a fresh install? `wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar`+ `php composer.phar -V`

Comment: Thank you @JensA.Koch! It was a pretty long story. I also had to update openSSL and then I was able to do the self-update

Comment: Glad you figured it out.